# How to add dropdown box , with hyperlinks, in Sharepoint 2010 Site

Tags: sharepoint, hyperlink, drop-down-menu

I have placed the dropdown box in my site, but i dont know how to bind each selection (ie url1, url2, etc..) with a new tab or page.

```
<form>
    <label>
        <u>S</u>earch Engines
    </label>
    <select accesskey="S" onchange="goToPage(this.options(this.selectedIndex).value)">
        <option selected>Please select one</option>
        <option value="http://search.msn.com/">MSN Search</option>
        <option value="http://www.google.com/">Google</option>
        <option value="http://www.search.com/">Search.com</option>
        <option value="http://www.dogpile.com/">Dogpile</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

I want the user to just pick one option and the page redirect him to the site he chose.

How can this be done, please?

Answer (score 1):

Following Code is Perfect as per your Requirement

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            Label lbl = new Label();
            sb.Append("<select accesskey='S' onchange='if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value'>");
            using (SPSite oSiteCollection = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
            {
                SPWebCollection collWebsites = oSiteCollection.AllWebs;


                foreach (SPWeb oWebsite in collWebsites)
                {
                    sb.Append("<option value='"+oWebsite.Url+"'>"+oWebsite.Name+"</option>");
                }
            }
            sb.Append("</select>");
            lbl.Text = sb.ToString();
            this.Controls.Add(lbl);
```

Just add to your Webpart and Deploy it..Bingo :)

Comment: @jigs-but this is perfect for beginner of sharepoint developer.

Comment: @MaksMatsveyeu : But that is perfect solution and no need for take Dropdownlist so....

Answer (score 0):

Just do this way:-

```
<select name="siteURL" accesskey="S" onchange="window.open(siteURL.options[selectedIndex].value)">
```

Comment: @GiorgosTekos: if this is correct, then click the checkmark and up arrow on the left.

Answer (score -1):

Please add this code onto your ascx:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlSites" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="SiteSelected" ></asp:DropDownList>
```

And add this code in the code behind:

```
private void BindSiteDropDown()
        {
            var sites = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                            {
                                {"MSN Search", "http://search.msn.com/"},
                                {"Google", "http://google.com"}
                            };
            ddlSites.Items.Clear();
            foreach (var site in sites)
            {
                ddlSites.Items.Add(new ListItem(site.Key, site.Value));
            }
        }

        protected void SiteSelected(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Page.Response.Redirect(((DropDownList)sender).SelectedValue);
        }
```

and call the BindSiteDropDown() method in the page load, for example like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(!IsPostBack)BindSiteDropDown();
        }
```